# JSFiddle get local html page for testing

Tags: jsfiddle

I'm new to JSFiddle but really like it. Don't fully understand how to load a local html page as a DOM to work with in Fiddle. looked at echo\html\ but don't know where to direct the actual URL link to get my full html page? html is very large and would need to escape thousands of ' to get it working. I know about Cross Domain issue so I've tried putting my html table in another Fiddle and calling it, that way its not cross domain.

http://jsfiddle.net/jeffbarclay/HGSvJ/

I would ideally like to get my html from my server like: http://www.myserver.com/myhtml.html

```
$(function(){
$.ajaxSetup ({
    cache: false
});
var ajax_load = "<img src='http://automobiles.honda.com/images/current-offers/small-loading.gif' alt='loading...' />";
var loadUrl = "http://jsfiddle.net/jeffbarclay/MvHTR/show/";
$("#loadbasic").click(function(){
    $("#result").html(ajax_load).load(loadUrl);
});
```

});

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved: had to use different link in jsfiddle to get results.
Here is working jsfiddle:
[JSFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/jeffbarclay/HGSvJ/)

```
$(function(){

$.ajaxSetup ({
    cache: false
});
var ajax_load = "<img src='http://automobiles.honda.com/images/current-offers/small-loading.gif' alt='loading...' />";

var loadUrl = "http://fiddle.jshell.net/jeffbarclay/MvHTR/show/";
    $("#loadbasic").click(function(){
    $("#result").html(ajax_load).load(loadUrl);
});
});
```